# No pre-configured android emulators when I installed Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, emulation

I installed xamarin, and from what I've looked up, there are meant to be emulators there ready to go. When I installed it, there were no emulators pre-configured at all. I attempted to make my own, but any I've done don't work. Any tips? Totally new to all this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a gander at the emulator documentation. There are many options available to you:

**VS Emulator**

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/

**SDK Emulator**

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/